# How to comment on goodness of loss functions?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I have two loss functions $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ to train my model. The model is predominantly a classification model. Both $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ takes two variants of the focal loss [[reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002)]. $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ takes as input the same class probabilities and a hyper-parameter $\gamma$. The formulation of $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ are distinct. It is possible to mathematically show that

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_1\geq\mathcal{L}_2.
\end{equation}

Based on this information can we comment on the useful-ness of $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$? i.e. which of $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ is more useful to train the model?

Comment: There's no mathematical way to tell why one loss function is better than another.  The closest you could get is specifying certain properties you hope a loss function to have, and then prove it obeys those properties. And an inequality between two loss functions is not in itself meaningful. e.g., if $L$ is any nonnegative loss function then $\frac{1}{2}L \leq L$, but $L$ and $L/2$ are equivalent in the sense any model that optimizes one will optimize the other.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the gradients for $L$ will be higher than the gradients for $\frac{1}{2}L$. Is that a point worth discussing? Also can we commnet on the sensitivity of the loss wit respect to the parameters?